# 552 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed limit

Tags: postfix

I already edited the main.cf file like this:

```
message_size_limit = 25600000
service postfix restart

postconf message_size_limit
message_size_limit = 25600000
```

I tried to send a mail with 18GB of total attachments and the log still showed:

```
NOQUEUE: reject: MAIL
552 5.3.4 Message size exceeds fixed limit; proto=ESMTP
```

Does something else can cause this?

Comment: [SMTP  wasn't designed/recommended to send a big file](http://serverfault.com/a/304425/218590)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I needed an even bigger limit.

> When sending an attachment, it's first converted to text (MIME), which
>   causes it to be a bit larger... 25% - 33% larger, if I remember
>   correctly.

https://www.virtualmin.com/node/35034#comment-139301

Answer (score 0):

message_size_limit is measured in bytes.

> message_size_limit = 25600000

for 18GB, you need 3 additional zeroes to the number.

Comment: no matter, this would kill any server/client implementation - smtp was and is not made for sharing such waste